# Адресация страниц в WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, cms

Действую согласно [Учебный курс по wordpress](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC), [Урок 9. Произвольные типы записей](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7Q6aB5u5b0&list=PL3LQJkGQtzc6Nwz67GGrMdqxim1c0H5DC&index=10&t=203s). Есть страница `http://wordpresstestsite.ru/portfolio/` (файл `C:\OpenServer\domains\wordpresstestsite.ru\wp-content\themes\sparrow\portfolio.php`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код вывода работ портфолио (блоков справа - `Geometrics`, `Console` и т.д. Cм. Скриншот сверху)

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Портфолио
*/
?>

<?php get_header('portfolio'); ?>

   <!-- Content
   ================================================== -->
   <div class="content-outer">

      <div id="page-content" class="row portfolio">

         <section class="entry cf">

            <div id="secondary"  class="four columns entry-details">

               <h1>Our Portfolio.</h1>

               <p class="lead">Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,
               nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh.</p>

               <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,
               nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate
               cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a
               ornare odio.</p>

            </div> <!-- Secondary End-->

            <div id="primary" class="eight columns portfolio-list">

               <div id="portfolio-wrapper" class="bgrid-halves cf">
               
               <?php
                    $post_cycle_counter=0;
                    $args=array(
                        'numberposts'=> 7,
                        'orderby'     => 'date',
                        'order'       => 'ASC',                     
                        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                        'suppress_filters' => true                  
                    );
                    $posts = get_posts($args);
                    
                    foreach ($posts as $post){ setup_postdata($post);
                        if ($post_cycle_counter%2==0) :
                        ?>
                            <div class="columns portfolio-item first">
                                <div class="item-wrap">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                                        <div class="link-icon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="portfolio-item-meta">
                                        <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <div class="columns portfolio-item">
                                <div class="item-wrap">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                                        <div class="link-icon"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></div>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="portfolio-item-meta">
                                        <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php
                        $post_cycle_counter++;
                    }
                    
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                        ?>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- primary end-->

         </section> <!-- end section -->

      </div> <!-- #page-content end-->

   </div> <!-- content End-->
```

Работы портфолио в WordPress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При щелчке на 1-ой работе `Geometrics` на странице с портфолио (см. 1-й скриншот) браузер переходит на страницу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему гиперссылка `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">` в коде `C:\OpenServer\domains\wordpresstestsite.ru\wp-content\themes\sparrow\portfolio.php` ведет на страницу 404.php?

Подскажите как добиться отображения страницы с работой `Geometrics`. Должно быть как на

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл `C:\OpenServer\domains\wordpresstestsite.ru\wp-content\themes\sparrow\portfolio-post.php` (файл с работой Geometrics - куда переходим по ссылке со страницы со всеми портфолио) имеет следующее содержание

```html
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page with portfolio works
Template Post Type: portfolio
*/
?>

<?php get_header('works'); ?>

   <!-- Content
   ================================================== -->
   <div class="content-outer">

      <div id="page-content" class="row portfolio">

         <section class="entry cf">

            <div id="secondary"  class="four columns entry-details">

                  <h1>Geometrics.</h1>

                  <div class="entry-description">

                     <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,
                     nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate
                     cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a
                     ornare odio.</p>

                  </div>

                  <ul class="portfolio-meta-list">
                           <li><span>Date: </span>January 2014</li>
                           <li><span>Client </span>Styleshout</li>
                           <li><span>Skills: </span>Photoshop, Photography, Branding</li>
                      </ul>

                  <a class="button" href="http://behance.net">View project</a>

            </div> <!-- secondary End-->

            <div id="primary" class="eight columns">

               <div class="entry-media">

                  <img src="images/portfolio/entries/geometric-backgrounds-01.jpg" alt="" />

                  <img src="images/portfolio/entries/geometric-backgrounds-02.jpg" alt="" />

               </div>

               <div class="entry-excerpt">

                      <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor,
                  nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate
                  cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. </p>

                    </div>

            </div> <!-- primary end-->

         </section> <!-- end section -->

         <ul class="post-nav cf">
               <li class="prev"><a href="#" rel="prev"><strong>Previous Entry</strong> Duis Sed Odio Sit Amet Nibh Vulputate</a></li>
                <li class="next"><a href="#" rel="next"><strong>Next Entry</strong> Morbi Elit Consequat Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>

      </div>

   </div> <!-- content End-->

   <!-- Tweets Section
   ================================================== -->
   <section id="tweets">

      <div class="row">

         <div class="tweeter-icon align-center">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
         </div>

         <ul id="twitter" class="align-center">
            <li>
               <span>
               This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
               Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum
               <a href="#">http://t.co/CGIrdxIlI3</a>
               </span>
               <b><a href="#">2 Days Ago</a></b>
            </li>
            <!--
            <li>
               <span>
               This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
               Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum
               <a href="#">http://t.co/CGIrdxIlI3</a>
               </span>
               <b><a href="#">3 Days Ago</a></b>
            </li>
            -->
         </ul>

         <p class="align-center"><a href="#" class="button">Follow us</a></p>

      </div>

   </section> <!-- Tweet Section End-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

P.S. Физически папки portfolio не существует

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка `http://wordpresstestsite.ru/portfolio/` создана wordpress автоматически. Пытался приткнуть файл `single.php` (или со схожим названием) (возможно не все варианты перебрал - поэтому предлагайте) - не получилось отобразить страницу `Geometrics`. Подскажите в связи с https://schtirlitz.ru/800/600/https/ubuntulinuxx.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/template-hierarchy-retina-dark.jpg как именовать страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо названия файла `portfolio-post.php` необходимо было использовать `single-portfolio-geometrics.php`.